# Would it be technically possible to create a "fat"/"Universal" Windows DLL?

Tags: windows, dll, universal-binary

Not withstanding that there is currently no tool that can create one, is it possible to have put both x64 and x86 symbols into a DLL, and have it work on both x64 and x86?

Creating one would be possible if there is some sort of specification/hack that would allow the Windows DLL loader to skip over incompatible symbols etc...

Comment: What would be needed would be support from the OS loader that is not presently available.

Comment: are there no hacks that can be performed that either invalidate the other bitness symbols or "hide" the other bitness section from it. I was kind of hoping some obscure experiment had revealed such a "bug/feature" somewhere in the last 10 years :)

Comment: No there are no hacks. Life is easiest if you just go with the flow. Have separate 32 and 64 bit versions of your DLLs.

Comment: The Sysinternals tools combine 32-bit and 64-bit EXEs into one, but that approach wouldn't work for DLLs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327228/combine-x86-and-x64-executables-in-single-executable-like-sysinternals-tools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a DLL contains only one header, IMAGE_FILE_HEADER [in the SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680313%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Which contains the Machine field, it indicates what kind of code the DLL contains.  There's no way to specify more than one machine type.

Comment: Specifically, it's not possible for PE format DLLs, and the OS hasn't ever bothered to support a format supporting sections for multiple architectures, except...

Answer (score 0):

Files on an NTFS filesystem are perfectly capable of containing multiple PE binaries, using NTFS alternate data streams.  However, a google search suggests that attempts to use `LoadLibrary` with streams have met with failure.